# Taylor Series in MIPS assembly

Tags: assembly, mips, taylor-series

I'm trying to calculate the Taylor Series

> 1 + *x* + *x*<sup>2</sup> / 2! + *x*<sup>3</sup> / 3! + ... + *x*<sup>10</sup> / 10!.

My program gives me infinity every time, I'm brand new to MIPS. I am only concerned about the input when it is between 0 and 10, inclusive.  we are stopping at *x*<sup>*n*</sup>/*n!* when *n* = 10. Heres what I came up with:

```c
# A program to first, find the power of x^n and the factorial of n. x,n are both between 0-10 inclusive. Then it finds the taylor series
    .data
pr1:    .asciiz "Enter Float x: "

    .text
    .globl main
main: 
    la $a0, pr1     # prompt user for x
    li $v0,4        # print string
    syscall
    li $v0, 6       # read single 
    syscall         
    mtc1 $v0, $f0       # f0 <--- x

exponent:           # f0 --> x
    mul.s $f1, $f0, $f0     # f1 --> x^2
    mul.s $f2, $f1, $f0 # f2 --> x^3
    mul.s $f3, $f2, $f0 # f3 --> x^4
    mul.s $f4, $f3, $f0 # f4 --> x^5
    mul.s $f5, $f4, $f0 # f5 --> x^6
    mul.s $f6, $f5, $f0 # f6 --> x^7
    mul.s $f7, $f6, $f0     # f7 --> x^8
    mul.s $f8, $f7, $f0 # f8 --> x^9
    mul.s $f9, $f8, $f0 # f9 --> x^10
factorial:
        li $s0, 1       # n = 10
        li $t0, 1

        add $t0, $t0, $s0   # t0 = 2! = 2

        add $t1, $t0, $s0   # t1 = 3
        mul $t1, $t1, $t0   # t1 = 3! = 6

        add $t2, $t0, $t0   # t2 = 4
        mul $t2, $t2, $t1   # t2 = 4! = 24

        addi $t3, $t1, -1   # t3 = 5
        mul $t3, $t3, $t2   # t3 = 5! = 120

        add $t4, $t1, $zero # t4 = 6
        mul $t4, $t4, $t3   # t4 = 6! = 720

        addi $t5, $t1, 1    # t5 = 7
        mul $t5, $t5, $t4   # t5 = 7! = 5040

        add $t6, $t1, $t0   # t6 = 8
        mul $t6, $t6, $t5   # t6 = 8! = 40320

        add $t7, $t1, $t0
        addi $t7, $t7, 1    # t7 = 9
        mul $t7, $t7, $t6   # t7 = 9! = 362880

        mul $s1, $t0, 5     # s1 = 10
        mul $s1, $s1, $t7   # s1 = 10! = 3628800    

taylor:
    mtc1 $s0, $f10      # $f10 = 1
    cvt.s.w $f10, $f10  # convert to float
    add.s $f0, $f0, $f10    # = 1 + x

    mtc1 $t0, $f10      # move n! to cp1
    cvt.s.w $f10, $f10  # convert to float 
    div.s $f10, $f10, $f1   # divide x^n/ n
    add.s $f0, $f0, $f10    # = 1 + x + x^2/2!

    mtc1 $t1, $f10      # move n! to cp1
    cvt.s.w $f10, $f10  # convert to float 
    div.s $f10, $f10, $f2   # divide x^n/ n
    add.s $f0, $f0, $f10    # = 1 + x +.. + x^3/3!

    mtc1 $t2, $f10      # move n! to cp1
    cvt.s.w $f10, $f10  # convert to float 
    div.s $f10, $f10, $f3   # divide x^n/ n
    add.s $f0, $f0, $f10    # = 1 + x +..+ x^4/4!

    mtc1 $t3, $f10      # move n! to cp1
    cvt.s.w $f10, $f10  # convert to float 
    div.s $f10, $f10, $f4   # divide x^n/ n
    add.s $f0, $f0, $f10    # = 1 + x + x^5/5!

    mtc1 $t4, $f10      # move n! to cp1
    cvt.s.w $f10, $f10  # convert to float 
    div.s $f10, $f10, $f5   # divide x^n/ n
    add.s $f0, $f0, $f10    # = 1 + x + x^6/6!

    mtc1 $t5, $f10      # move n! to cp1
    cvt.s.w $f10, $f10  # convert to float 
    div.s $f10, $f10, $f6   # divide x^n/ n
    add.s $f0, $f0, $f10    # = 1 + x + x^7/7!

    mtc1 $t6, $f10      # move n! to cp1
    cvt.s.w $f10, $f10  # convert to float 
    div.s $f10, $f10, $f7   # divide x^n/ n
    add.s $f0, $f0, $f10    # = 1 + x + x^8/8!

    mtc1 $t7, $f10      # move n! to cp1
    cvt.s.w $f10, $f10  # convert to float 
    div.s $f10, $f10, $f8   # divide x^n/ n
    add.s $f0, $f0, $f10    # = 1 + x + x^9/9!

    mtc1 $s1, $f10      # move n! to cp1
    cvt.s.w $f10, $f10  # convert to float 
    div.s $f10, $f10, $f9   # divide x^n/ n
    add.s $f0, $f0, $f10    # = 1 + x + x^10/10!
end:
        mov.s $f12, $f0     # argument
        li $v0, 2       # print float
        syscall         
        li $v0, 10
        syscall
```

Comment: Use the debugger to single step and see where the error is.

Comment: I don't know how to do that

Comment: You'd better learn it, unless you can make error free programs. Which you obviously can't :) Since you commented your code nicely, it looks like it would be easy to catch where the machine is not doing what the comment says. One obvious problem is that the `read_float` returns the number in `$f0` already so you should not try to move `$v0` in there.

Answer (score 2):

To start with, you have a few bugs:

(1) As Jester mentioned, your "read float" syscall had a bug.

(2) You're calculating `factorial(n)` but the Taylor cosine series uses `factorial(2n)`, so it increases more quickly.

(3) Another problem you may be having [*would* be having with the correct factorial] is that you're using integer math for the factorial.  When calculating to 10 iterations, the factorial will overflow a 32 bit integer. For 10 iterations, we end up with [at least] `factorial(18)` which is ~6.4e15 (i.e. does *not* fit in a 32 integer). With integer math, the factorial, instead of increasing steadily, will "oscillate" whenever the value wraps 32 bits.

I've taken a slightly different approach.

Rather than pre-calculate everything [as you've done], I created a solution that uses a loop. That may or may not help you with debugging your own implementation, but I'd be remiss if I didn't recommend refactoring.

Below is asm code for the loop implementation. There is also a C version that I used to debug the algorithm first. There is also an asm version with some debug statements.

---

**Rationale:**

You're trying to calculate `cos` using Taylor Series summation/expansion [to 10 iterations]. The formula *does* use a "summation" operator, after all.

You're precalculating all `x^n` terms and all factorial terms and putting them in different registers. That's fine as MIPS has 32 FP registers. But, with double precision, we'd have to use two registers, so that would mean only 16 numbers. In a way, what you did is the equivalent of a compiler doing "loop unrolling".

Another issue is that it can be hard to keep track of all those registers. What is holding what value.

And, suppose, the problem were to use 20 iterations instead of 10. We'd probably run out of registers. In practice, this might be necessary for other series expansions because we might not get convergence as quickly.

So, I'd recommend using a loop. Each power term is easily calculated from the previous one. Likewise, for each factorial.

Another advantage to using the loop approach is that rather than using a fixed number of iterations, we can monitor the term value [`cur`] (which is getting smaller and smaller) and if it changes by less than a certain amount [or is smaller than that amount] (e.g. for double precision, 1e-14) we can stop because our values won't get any better than the precision our floating point format [and hardware] affords us.

*Note:* This is *not* shown below but is easy enough to implement.

---

Here's the asm version. The variable names used in the comments refer to the variable names used in the C code [which follows afterward].

```
# A program to calculate cos(x) using taylor series
    .data
pr1:        .asciiz     "Enter Float x: "
sym_fnc:    .asciiz     "cos(x): "
nl:         .asciiz     "\n"

    .text
    .globl  main

main:
    li      $s7,0                   # clear debug flag #+

    # prompt user for x value
    li      $v0,4                   # print string
    la      $a0,pr1                 # prompt user for x
    syscall

    # read user's x value
    li      $v0,6                   # read float
    syscall

    jal     qcos

    la      $a0,sym_fnc             # string
    jal     prtflt

    li      $v0,10
    syscall

# qcos -- calculate cosine
#
# RETURNS:
#   f0 -- cos(x)
#
# arguments:
#   f0 -- x value
#
# registers:
#   f2 -- x value
#   f4 -- sum
#   f6 -- xpow (x^n)
#   f8 -- n2m1
#   f10 -- factorial (nfac)
#   f12 -- RESERVED (used in pflt)
#   f14 -- current term
#   f16 -- x^2
#
#   f18 -- a one value
#
#   t0 -- zero value
#   t1 -- one value
#
#   t6 -- negation flag
#   t7 -- iteration count
qcos:
    move    $s0,$ra                 # save return address
    mov.s   $f2,$f0                 # save x value

    mul.s   $f16,$f2,$f2            # get x^2

    li      $t0,0                   # get a zero
    li      $t1,1                   # get a one

    li      $t6,1                   # start with positive term

    # xpow = 1
    mtc1    $t1,$f6                 # xpow = 1
    cvt.s.w $f6,$f6                 # convert to float

    # n2m1 = 0
    mtc1    $t0,$f8                 # n2m1 = 0
    cvt.s.w $f8,$f8                 # convert to float

    # nfac = 1
    mtc1    $t1,$f10                # nfac = 1
    cvt.s.w $f10,$f10               # convert to float

    # get a one value
    mtc1    $t1,$f18                # onetmp = 1
    cvt.s.w $f18,$f18               # convert to float

    # zero the sum
    mtc1    $t0,$f4                 # sum = 0
    cvt.s.w $f4,$f4                 # convert to float

    li      $t7,10                  # set number of iterations

cosloop:

    div.s   $f14,$f6,$f10           # cur = xpow / nfac

    # apply the term to the sum
    bgtz    $t6,cospos              # do positive? yes, fly
    sub.s   $f4,$f4,$f14            # subtract the term
    b       cosneg

cospos:
    add.s   $f4,$f4,$f14            # add the term

cosneg:

    subi    $t7,$t7,1               # bump down iteration count
    blez    $t7,cosdone             # are we done? if yes, fly

    # now calculate intermediate values for _next_ term

    # get _next_ power term
    mul.s   $f6,$f6,$f16            # xpow *= x2

    # go from factorial(2n) to factorial(2n+1)
    add.s   $f8,$f8,$f18            # n2m1 += 1
    mul.s   $f10,$f10,$f8           # nfac *= n2m1

    # go from factorial(2n+1) to factorial(2n+1+1)
    add.s   $f8,$f8,$f18            # n2m1 += 1
    mul.s   $f10,$f10,$f8           # nfac *= n2m1

    neg     $t6,$t6                 # flip sign for next time
    j       cosloop

cosdone:
    mov.s   $f0,$f4                 # set return value

    move    $ra,$s0                 # restore return address
    jr      $ra

# dbgflt -- debug print float number
dbgflt:
    bnez    $s7,prtflt
    jr      $ra

# dbgnum -- debug print int number
dbgnum:
    beqz    $s7,dbgnumdone
    li      $v0,1
    syscall

dbgnumdone:
    jr      $ra

# dbgprt -- debug print float number
dbgprt:
    beqz    $s7,dbgprtdone
    li      $v0,4
    syscall

dbgprtdone:
    jr      $ra

# prtflt -- print float number
#
# arguments:
#   a0 -- prefix string (symbol name)
#   f12 -- number to print
prtflt:
    li      $v0,4                   # syscall: print string
    syscall

    li      $v0,2                   # print float
    syscall

    li      $v0,4                   # syscall: print string
    la      $a0,nl                  # print newline
    syscall

    jr      $ra
```

---

Here's the C code [it also has code for `sin(x)`]:

```
// mipsqsin/mipstaylor -- fast sine/cosine calculation

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define ITERMAX     10

// qcos -- calculate cosine
double
qcos(double x)
{
    int iteridx;
    double x2;
    double cur;
    int neg;
    double xpow;
    double n2m1;
    double nfac;
    double sum;

    // square of x
    x2 = x * x;

    // values for initial terms where n==0:
    xpow = 1.0;
    n2m1 = 0.0;
    nfac = 1.0;
    neg = 1;

    sum = 0.0;
    iteridx = 0;

    // NOTES:
    // (1) with the setup above, we can just use the loop without any special
    //     casing
    while (1) {
        // calculate current value
        cur = xpow / nfac;

        // apply it to sum
        if (neg < 0)
            sum -= cur;
        else
            sum += cur;

        // bug out when done
        if (++iteridx >= ITERMAX)
            break;

        // now calculate intermediate values for _next_ sum term

        // get _next_ power term
        xpow *= x2;

        // go from factorial(2n) to factorial(2n+1)
        n2m1 += 1.0;
        nfac *= n2m1;

        // now get factorial(2n+1+1)
        n2m1 += 1.0;
        nfac *= n2m1;

        // flip sign
        neg = -neg;
    }

    return sum;
}

// qsin -- calculate sine
double
qsin(double x)
{
    int iteridx;
    double x2;
    double cur;
    int neg;
    double xpow;
    double n2m1;
    double nfac;
    double sum;

    // square of x
    x2 = x * x;

    // values for initial terms where n==0:
    xpow = x;
    n2m1 = 1.0;
    nfac = 1.0;
    neg = 1;

    sum = 0.0;
    iteridx = 0;

    // NOTES:
    // (1) with the setup above, we can just use the loop without any special
    //     casing
    while (1) {
        // calculate current value
        cur = xpow / nfac;

        // apply it to sum
        if (neg < 0)
            sum -= cur;
        else
            sum += cur;

        // bug out when done
        if (++iteridx >= ITERMAX)
            break;

        // now calculate intermediate values for _next_ sum term

        // get _next_ power term
        xpow *= x2;

        // go from factorial(2n+1) to factorial(2n+1+1)
        n2m1 += 1.0;
        nfac *= n2m1;

        // now get factorial(2n+1+1+1)
        n2m1 += 1.0;
        nfac *= n2m1;

        // flip sign
        neg = -neg;
    }

    return sum;
}

// testfnc -- test function
void
testfnc(int typ,const char *sym)
{
    double (*efnc)(double);
    double (*qfnc)(double);
    double vale;
    double valq;
    double x;
    double dif;
    int iter;

    switch (typ) {
    case 0:
        efnc = cos;
        qfnc = qcos;
        break;

    case 1:
        efnc = sin;
        qfnc = qsin;
        break;

    default:
        efnc = NULL;
        qfnc = NULL;
        break;
    }

    iter = 0;
    for (x = 0.0;  x <= M_PI_2;  x += 0.001, ++iter) {
        vale = efnc(x);
        valq = qfnc(x);

        dif = vale - valq;
        dif = fabs(dif);

        printf("%s: %d x=%.15f e=%.15f q=%.15f dif=%.15f %s\n",
            sym,iter,x,vale,valq,dif,(dif < 1e-14) ? "PASS" : "FAIL");
    }
}

// main -- main program
int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{

    testfnc(0,"cos");
    testfnc(1,"sin");

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here's the asm version with debug statements I used. This is "printf debugging", just like in C.

Alternatively, both the `mars` and `spim` simulators have builtin GUI debugging. You can single step the code by clicking on a single button. You can see a live display of all register values.

*Note:* Personally, I prefer `mars`. This works with `mars` but I don't know if `spim` supports `.eqv` pseudo ops.

```
# A program to calculate cos(x) using taylor series

    .data
pr1:        .asciiz     "Enter Float x: "
sym_fnc:    .asciiz     "cos(x): "
nl:         .asciiz     "\n"

#+ddef  f2,x
    .eqv    fpr_x           $f2     #+
sym_x:      .asciiz     "x[f2]: "       #+
#+
#+ddef  f16,x2
    .eqv    fpr_x2          $f16    #+
sym_x2:     .asciiz     "x2[f16]: "     #+
#+
#+ddef  f4,sum
    .eqv    fpr_sum         $f4     #+
sym_sum:    .asciiz     "sum[f4]: "     #+
#+
#+ddef  f6,xpow
    .eqv    fpr_xpow        $f6     #+
sym_xpow:   .asciiz     "xpow[f6]: "    #+
#+
#+ddef  f8,n2m1
    .eqv    fpr_n2m1        $f8     #+
sym_n2m1:   .asciiz     "n2m1[f8]: "    #+
#+
#+ddef  f10,nfac
    .eqv    fpr_nfac        $f10    #+
sym_nfac:   .asciiz     "nfac[f10]: "   #+
#+
#+ddef  f14,cur
    .eqv    fpr_cur         $f14    #+
sym_cur:    .asciiz     "cur[f14]: "    #+
    #+

    .text
    .globl  main

main:
    #+dask
    la      $a0,dbgask              # prompt user #+
    li      $v0,4                   # print string #+
    syscall                         #+
    # get debug flag #+
    li      $v0,5                   #+
    syscall                         #+
    move    $s7,$v0                 #+
    .data                           #+
dbgask:     .asciiz     "Debug (0/1) ? "    #+
    .text                           #+
    #+

    # prompt user for x value
    li      $v0,4                   # print string
    la      $a0,pr1                 # prompt user for x
    syscall

    # read user's x value
    li      $v0,6                   # read float
    syscall

    jal     qcos

    la      $a0,sym_fnc             # string
    jal     prtflt

    li      $v0,10
    syscall

# qcos -- calculate cosine
#
# RETURNS:
#   f0 -- cos(x)
#
# arguments:
#   f0 -- x value
#
# registers:
#   f2 -- x value
#   f4 -- sum
#   f6 -- xpow (x^n)
#   f8 -- n2m1
#   f10 -- factorial (nfac)
#   f12 -- RESERVED (used in pflt)
#   f14 -- current term
#   f16 -- x^2
#
#   f18 -- a one value
#
#   t0 -- zero value
#   t1 -- one value
#
#   t6 -- negation flag
#   t7 -- iteration count
qcos:
    move    $s0,$ra                 # save return address
    mov.s   $f2,$f0                 # save x value
    #+dflt  x
    la      $a0,sym_x               #+
    mov.s   $f12,fpr_x              #+
    jal     dbgflt                  #+
    #+

    mul.s   $f16,$f2,$f2            # get x^2
    #+dflt  x2
    la      $a0,sym_x2              #+
    mov.s   $f12,fpr_x2             #+
    jal     dbgflt                  #+
    #+

    li      $t0,0                   # get a zero
    li      $t1,1                   # get a one

    li      $t6,1                   # start with positive term

    # xpow = 1
    mtc1    $t1,$f6                 # xpow = 1
    cvt.s.w $f6,$f6                 # convert to float

    # n2m1 = 0
    mtc1    $t0,$f8                 # n2m1 = 0
    cvt.s.w $f8,$f8                 # convert to float

    # nfac = 1
    mtc1    $t1,$f10                # nfac = 1
    cvt.s.w $f10,$f10               # convert to float

    # get a one value
    mtc1    $t1,$f18                # onetmp = 1
    cvt.s.w $f18,$f18               # convert to float

    # zero the sum
    mtc1    $t0,$f4                 # sum = 0
    cvt.s.w $f4,$f4                 # convert to float

    li      $t7,10                  # set number of iterations

cosloop:
    #+dprt  "cosloop: LOOP iter="
    la      $a0,dprt_1              #+
    jal     dbgprt                  #+
    .data                           #+
dprt_1:     .asciiz     "cosloop: LOOP iter="   #+
    .text                           #+
    #+
    #+dnum  $t7
    move    $a0,$t7                 #+
    jal     dbgnum                  #+
    #+
    #+dprt  "\n"
    la      $a0,dprt_2              #+
    jal     dbgprt                  #+
    .data                           #+
dprt_2:     .asciiz     "\n"            #+
    .text                           #+
    #+

    #+dflt  xpow
    la      $a0,sym_xpow            #+
    mov.s   $f12,fpr_xpow           #+
    jal     dbgflt                  #+
    #+
    #+dflt  nfac
    la      $a0,sym_nfac            #+
    mov.s   $f12,fpr_nfac           #+
    jal     dbgflt                  #+
    #+

    div.s   $f14,$f6,$f10           # cur = xpow / nfac
    #+dflt  cur
    la      $a0,sym_cur             #+
    mov.s   $f12,fpr_cur            #+
    jal     dbgflt                  #+
    #+

    # apply the term to the sum
    bgtz    $t6,cospos              # do positive? yes, fly
    #+dprt  "costerm: NEG\n"
    la      $a0,dprt_3              #+
    jal     dbgprt                  #+
    .data                           #+
dprt_3:     .asciiz     "costerm: NEG\n"    #+
    .text                           #+
    #+
    sub.s   $f4,$f4,$f14            # subtract the term
    b       cosneg

cospos:
    #+dprt  "costerm: POS\n"
    la      $a0,dprt_4              #+
    jal     dbgprt                  #+
    .data                           #+
dprt_4:     .asciiz     "costerm: POS\n"    #+
    .text                           #+
    #+
    add.s   $f4,$f4,$f14            # add the term

cosneg:
    #+dflt  sum
    la      $a0,sym_sum             #+
    mov.s   $f12,fpr_sum            #+
    jal     dbgflt                  #+
    #+

    subi    $t7,$t7,1               # bump down iteration count
    blez    $t7,cosdone             # are we done? if yes, fly

    # now calculate intermediate values for _next_ term
    #+dprt  "cosloop: CALC\n"
    la      $a0,dprt_5              #+
    jal     dbgprt                  #+
    .data                           #+
dprt_5:     .asciiz     "cosloop: CALC\n"   #+
    .text                           #+
    #+

    # get _next_ power term
    mul.s   $f6,$f6,$f16            # xpow *= x2

    # go from factorial(2n) to factorial(2n+1)
    add.s   $f8,$f8,$f18            # n2m1 += 1
    #+dflt  n2m1
    la      $a0,sym_n2m1            #+
    mov.s   $f12,fpr_n2m1           #+
    jal     dbgflt                  #+
    #+
    mul.s   $f10,$f10,$f8           # nfac *= n2m1
    #+dflt  nfac
    la      $a0,sym_nfac            #+
    mov.s   $f12,fpr_nfac           #+
    jal     dbgflt                  #+
    #+

    # go from factorial(2n+1) to factorial(2n+1+1)
    add.s   $f8,$f8,$f18            # n2m1 += 1
    #+dflt  n2m1
    la      $a0,sym_n2m1            #+
    mov.s   $f12,fpr_n2m1           #+
    jal     dbgflt                  #+
    #+
    mul.s   $f10,$f10,$f8           # nfac *= n2m1
    #+dflt  nfac
    la      $a0,sym_nfac            #+
    mov.s   $f12,fpr_nfac           #+
    jal     dbgflt                  #+
    #+

    neg     $t6,$t6                 # flip sign for next time
    j       cosloop

cosdone:
    mov.s   $f0,$f4                 # set return value

    move    $ra,$s0                 # restore return address
    jr      $ra

# dbgflt -- debug print float number
dbgflt:
    bnez    $s7,prtflt
    jr      $ra

# dbgnum -- debug print int number
dbgnum:
    beqz    $s7,dbgnumdone
    li      $v0,1
    syscall

dbgnumdone:
    jr      $ra

# dbgprt -- debug print float number
dbgprt:
    beqz    $s7,dbgprtdone
    li      $v0,4
    syscall

dbgprtdone:
    jr      $ra

# prtflt -- print float number
#
# arguments:
#   a0 -- prefix string (symbol name)
#   f12 -- number to print
prtflt:
    li      $v0,4                   # syscall: print string
    syscall

    li      $v0,2                   # print float
    syscall

    li      $v0,4                   # syscall: print string
    la      $a0,nl                  # print newline
    syscall

    jr      $ra
```

---

Here's the debug output log for a single value:

```
Debug (0/1) ? 1
Enter Float x: 0.123
x[f2]: 0.123
x2[f16]: 0.015129001
cosloop: LOOP iter=10
xpow[f6]: 1.0
nfac[f10]: 1.0
cur[f14]: 1.0
costerm: POS
sum[f4]: 1.0
cosloop: CALC
n2m1[f8]: 1.0
nfac[f10]: 1.0
n2m1[f8]: 2.0
nfac[f10]: 2.0
cosloop: LOOP iter=9
xpow[f6]: 0.015129001
nfac[f10]: 2.0
cur[f14]: 0.0075645004
costerm: NEG
sum[f4]: 0.9924355
cosloop: CALC
n2m1[f8]: 3.0
nfac[f10]: 6.0
n2m1[f8]: 4.0
nfac[f10]: 24.0
cosloop: LOOP iter=8
xpow[f6]: 2.2888667E-4
nfac[f10]: 24.0
cur[f14]: 9.536944E-6
costerm: POS
sum[f4]: 0.99244505
cosloop: CALC
n2m1[f8]: 5.0
nfac[f10]: 120.0
n2m1[f8]: 6.0
nfac[f10]: 720.0
cosloop: LOOP iter=7
xpow[f6]: 3.4628265E-6
nfac[f10]: 720.0
cur[f14]: 4.8094813E-9
costerm: NEG
sum[f4]: 0.99244505
cosloop: CALC
n2m1[f8]: 7.0
nfac[f10]: 5040.0
n2m1[f8]: 8.0
nfac[f10]: 40320.0
cosloop: LOOP iter=6
xpow[f6]: 5.2389105E-8
nfac[f10]: 40320.0
cur[f14]: 1.2993329E-12
costerm: POS
sum[f4]: 0.99244505
cosloop: CALC
n2m1[f8]: 9.0
nfac[f10]: 362880.0
n2m1[f8]: 10.0
nfac[f10]: 3628800.0
cosloop: LOOP iter=5
xpow[f6]: 7.925948E-10
nfac[f10]: 3628800.0
cur[f14]: 2.1841789E-16
costerm: NEG
sum[f4]: 0.99244505
cosloop: CALC
n2m1[f8]: 11.0
nfac[f10]: 3.99168E7
n2m1[f8]: 12.0
nfac[f10]: 4.790016E8
cosloop: LOOP iter=4
xpow[f6]: 1.1991168E-11
nfac[f10]: 4.790016E8
cur[f14]: 2.503367E-20
costerm: POS
sum[f4]: 0.99244505
cosloop: CALC
n2m1[f8]: 13.0
nfac[f10]: 6.2270208E9
n2m1[f8]: 14.0
nfac[f10]: 8.7178289E10
cosloop: LOOP iter=3
xpow[f6]: 1.8141439E-13
nfac[f10]: 8.7178289E10
cur[f14]: 2.0809583E-24
costerm: NEG
sum[f4]: 0.99244505
cosloop: CALC
n2m1[f8]: 15.0
nfac[f10]: 1.30767428E12
n2m1[f8]: 16.0
nfac[f10]: 2.09227885E13
cosloop: LOOP iter=2
xpow[f6]: 2.7446184E-15
nfac[f10]: 2.09227885E13
cur[f14]: 1.3117842E-28
costerm: POS
sum[f4]: 0.99244505
cosloop: CALC
n2m1[f8]: 17.0
nfac[f10]: 3.55687415E14
n2m1[f8]: 18.0
nfac[f10]: 6.4023735E15
cosloop: LOOP iter=1
xpow[f6]: 4.1523335E-17
nfac[f10]: 6.4023735E15
cur[f14]: 6.485616E-33
costerm: NEG
sum[f4]: 0.99244505
cos(x): 0.99244505

-- program is finished running --
```

Comment: What I noticed about the OP's fully-unrolled computation of x^n was that there were missed opportunities for ILP: Computing x^4 as (x^2)*(x^2) would mean it could happen in parallel with x^3=x^2*x, and so on for higher powers.  I assume most MIPS implementations have multi-cycle-latency pipelined FP multiply with better throughput than latency.  But doing the rest of the work for an iteration would also hide the mul latency. Also, using registers $f1..$f10 instead of $f0..$f9 would have been preferable, except that $f0=x^1 is the starting point, and a discontinuity in numbering would be worse.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah. Once I decided to rearchitect [I already had the C code from another SO answer of mine--again, for MIPS], I didn't look closely at OP's code after that [when I spotted the int math]. I interviewed at MIPS [the company] back in the '80s, and at that time, they _barely_ had the gates available to do things sequentially (i.e. the branch delay slot). MIPS still gets used for R/T embedded, and is implemented on a modern IC process, so OOO/ILP is quite possible.

Comment: @PeterCordes _Side note:_ I've been meaning to ask you. You seem to have an _extraordinary_ knowledge of the _model specific_ features/pipelines/etc for an x86 model. Where/how do you get this?

Comment: I read [Agner Fog's microarch pdf](http://agner.org/optimize), and stuff like [David Kanter's Haswell writeup](http://www.realworldtech.com/haswell-cpu/).  The whole Intel SnB-family is pretty similar, and I write enough SO answers that I usually don't have to even look up things about SnB.  It's a really nice design that removes a lot of the bottlenecks from previous designs (e.g. register read port stalls, and instruction decoding).  I love knowing how stuff works, so this kind of stuff just sticks in my memory pretty easily.

Comment: For a lot of answers, I just tab over to Agner Fog's instruction tables, which I have open in LibreOffice pretty much constantly.  I don't try to keep track of all the details for AMD CPUs; I know there are bottlenecks and gotchas besides just m-op count worse than on Intel when counting fused-domain uops.  Anyway, I tend to take a lot of time writing SO answers, since if I'm going to take time to answer at all, it's worth providing a complete and detailed answer.

Comment: re: superscalar MIPS: Remember that SGI used MIPS for a while, so some pretty serious high-end implementations of the ISA exist.  According to wikipedia: [r10k](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R10000#Description) is a 4-wide superscalar design with register renaming and OOO.  The FP multiplier and adder are pipelined.

Comment: IIRC, SGI was better funded, etc. than MIPS and had the _graphics_ that engrs drooled over. The guy who interviewed me at MIPS [which I had decided not to work for] called me back a year or two later, but neglected to mention he was now working at SGI [which I would have been interested in]. In those days, process tech grew rapidly, so a year gap actually _meant_ something. In 1989, Sun got Sparc. The first chip was ~40k gates or transistors [I can't remember which]