# C programming - combining power(x, n) and fact(n) functions together

Tags: c, function, for-loop

I've been working on a program that calculates sin(x), cos(x), and exp(x) without using `math.h` and compares them to the library values of their functions. I've been forbidden from actually using the basic power(x, n) and fact(n) functions. The only hint is that I have to do division before doing multiplication when combining the functions into one.

```
double power(double x, int n)
{
    int i;
    double prod=1.;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        prod = prod*x;
    }
    return prod;
}

double fact(int n)
{
    int i;
    double prod=1.;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        prod = prod*i;
    }
    return prod;
}
```

My idea is to somehow nest the for-loops together, and piecemeal the Taylor Expansion formula for each iteration of the loop, but I haven't had luck actually combining the two.
Any help or hint would be appreciated on how to combine these.

The other aspect of the program that confuses me is that there can only be a single input of X per iteration of the program, and therefore no dynamically defined 'n' for the loops.

Comment: I apologize that it’s unclear, it isn’t exactly clear to me either. The problem is that I need to implement sin(x), cos(x) and exp(x) by combining power and fact functions together and dividing power by fact within the loop, without using the <math.h> functions... and then matching the results with the library values.

Comment: The code bellow shows you how to calculate `sinx` using your 2 functions. Remember to give N some value (it is your precision) how close to the actual sinx

Answer (score 0):

Use Taylor series for the exponential: 
 `e^x = 1 + x/1! + x^2/2! + x^3/3!...` 
and using Euler after that you can calculate **sinx** and **cosx**.

Answer (score 0):

Part of this comes from my answer for doing this in MIPS assembly: [Taylor Series in MIPS assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36439699)

You can do Taylor series on the fly without having to call sub-functions. In the series, each term can be calculated from the previous term in a loop. (i.e. no need to call `fact` and/or `pow` repeatedly, where each starts from the beginning). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series

Anyway, here's code for `sin` and `cos`:

```
// mipstaylor/mipstaylor -- fast sine/cosine calculation

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define ITERMAX     10

// qcos -- calculate cosine
double
qcos(double x)
{
    int iteridx;
    double x2;
    double cur;
    int neg;
    double xpow;
    double n2m1;
    double nfac;
    double sum;

    // square of x
    x2 = x * x;

    // values for initial terms where n==0:
    xpow = 1.0;
    n2m1 = 0.0;
    nfac = 1.0;
    neg = 1;

    sum = 0.0;
    iteridx = 0;

    // NOTES:
    // (1) with the setup above, we can just use the loop without any special
    //     casing
    while (1) {
        // calculate current value
        cur = xpow / nfac;

        // apply it to sum
        if (neg < 0)
            sum -= cur;
        else
            sum += cur;

        // bug out when done
        if (++iteridx >= ITERMAX)
            break;

        // now calculate intermediate values for _next_ sum term

        // get _next_ power term
        xpow *= x2;

        // go from factorial(2n) to factorial(2n+1)
        n2m1 += 1.0;
        nfac *= n2m1;

        // now get factorial(2n+1+1)
        n2m1 += 1.0;
        nfac *= n2m1;

        // flip sign
        neg = -neg;
    }

    return sum;
}

// qsin -- calculate sine
double
qsin(double x)
{
    int iteridx;
    double x2;
    double cur;
    int neg;
    double xpow;
    double n2m1;
    double nfac;
    double sum;

    // square of x
    x2 = x * x;

    // values for initial terms where n==0:
    xpow = x;
    n2m1 = 1.0;
    nfac = 1.0;
    neg = 1;

    sum = 0.0;
    iteridx = 0;

    // NOTES:
    // (1) with the setup above, we can just use the loop without any special
    //     casing
    while (1) {
        // calculate current value
        cur = xpow / nfac;

        // apply it to sum
        if (neg < 0)
            sum -= cur;
        else
            sum += cur;

        // bug out when done
        if (++iteridx >= ITERMAX)
            break;

        // now calculate intermediate values for _next_ sum term

        // get _next_ power term
        xpow *= x2;

        // go from factorial(2n+1) to factorial(2n+1+1)
        n2m1 += 1.0;
        nfac *= n2m1;

        // now get factorial(2n+1+1+1)
        n2m1 += 1.0;
        nfac *= n2m1;

        // flip sign
        neg = -neg;
    }

    return sum;
}

// testfnc -- test function
void
testfnc(int typ,const char *sym)
{
    double (*efnc)(double);
    double (*qfnc)(double);
    double vale;
    double valq;
    double x;
    double dif;
    int iter;

    switch (typ) {
    case 0:
        efnc = cos;
        qfnc = qcos;
        break;

    case 1:
        efnc = sin;
        qfnc = qsin;
        break;

    default:
        efnc = NULL;
        qfnc = NULL;
        break;
    }

    iter = 0;
    for (x = 0.0;  x <= M_PI_2;  x += 0.001, ++iter) {
        vale = efnc(x);
        valq = qfnc(x);

        dif = vale - valq;
        dif = fabs(dif);

        printf("%s: %d x=%.15f e=%.15f q=%.15f dif=%.15f %s\n",
            sym,iter,x,vale,valq,dif,(dif < 1e-14) ? "PASS" : "FAIL");
    }
}

// main -- main program
int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{

    testfnc(0,"cos");
    testfnc(1,"sin");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to look at the changes between each successive term in the Taylor series expansion.  Let's start with e<sup>x</sup>:

```
e^x = 1 + x + x^2/2! + x^3/3! + x^4/4! + x^5/5! ...
```

Notice that each term is `x / n` times the prior term, where `n` is the term number.  So start with a term of 1, then multiply by the above expression to get the next term.

That gives you the following implementation:

```
double etox(double x)
{
    long double sum = 0;
    // term starts at 1
    long double term = 1;   
    // term number
    int i = 1;

    // continue until the term is below the precision of the current sum
    while (sum + term != sum) {
        sum += term;
        // new term is x/i times the prior term, where i is the term number
        term *= (long double)x / i;
        i++;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Note that with this implementation, you'll get some degree of error in the least significant digits.  If you start adding from a higher term number and work your way back, this can be avoided.

Similarly for sin(x) and cos(x):

```
sin(x) = x - x^3/3! + x^5/5! - x^7/7! + x^9/9! ...
cos(x) = 1 - x^2/2! + x^4/4! - x^6/6! + x^8/8! ...
```

Each term is `- (x*x) / ((2*n)*((2*n)-1))` times the prior term, where *n* is the term number.

I'll leave the the implementation of these two as an exercise for the reader.